# Как заменить Django переменные на JavaScript переменные в JSON масиве?

Tags: javascript, json, django

Есть массив в виде JSON, в котором у меня Django цикл с переменными:

```
    var dataJSONArray = JSON.parse('[
{% for client in clients %}
    {"firstName":"",
    "lastName":"{{ client.last_name }}",
    "email":"{{ client.email }}",
    "phone":"{{ client.phone }}",
    "company":"{{ client.company }}",
    "test":"{{ client.demo }}",
    "joined":"{{ client.date_joined }}",
    "paidOrder":"{{ client.orders.count }}/{{ client.get_payment_orders.count }}",
    "launches":"{{ client.get_finished_launches.count }}/{{ client.launched_products.count }}"}

{% endfor %}
]');
```

И он, понятное дело, не хочет парситься, ругается. Как тут можно безболезненно заменить Django-переменные на, скажем, JavaScript? Спасибо.

Comment: в/хоть\отформатировали\бы\код\чтобы\было\удобнее\читать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил:

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"clients":[{% for client in clients %}{"firstName":"","lastName":"{{client.last_name}}","email":"{{client.email}}","phone":"{{client.phone}}","company":"{{client.company}}","test":"{{client.demo}}","joined":"{{client.date_joined}}","paidOrder":"{{client.orders.count}}/{{client.get_payment_orders.count}}","launches":"{{client.get_finished_launches.count}}/{{client.launched_products.count}}"}{% if forloop.last %} {% else %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}]}'));
```

я брал такой массив с python

```
clients = [
        {
             "last_name": "Bobov",
             "email": "mail@gamil.com",
             "phone": "12",
             "company": "12",
             "demo": "12",
             "date_joined": "12",
             "orders": {"count": 12},
             "get_payment_orders": {"count": 1122},
             "get_finished_launches": {"count": 12},
             "launched_products": {"count": 252},
         },
        {
            "last_name": "B2obov",
            "email": "mail@gami4l.com",
            "phone": "1e2",
            "company": "1r2",
            "demo": "1t2",
            "date_joined": "w12",
            "orders": {"count": 152},
            "get_payment_orders": {"count": 13122},
            "get_finished_launches": {"count": 212},
            "launched_products": {"count": 2552},
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Не форматируйте JSON с помощью шаблонов. Даже если в тестинге всё будет хорошо, шанс, что вы получите самую неожиданную ошибку в самом неожиданном месте слишком велик.

Хороший способ — выделить отдельный url, из которого отдавать json, закодированный стандартными средствами питона (`from json import dumps`).